# React-Bootstrap onClick triggers accumulate(?) and execute many times on checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

What I'm experiencing is what seems like onClick listeners accumulating across renders and firing more and more times as I toggle a checkbox.

I'm mapping over an array to generate the checkboxes, like this:

```
  const list = permissions[cat].map((p) => {
    // map the role's permissions to the checked state of the "all" permission checkboxes
    const checked = _.findWhere(role.permissions, {id: p.id}) ? true : false;

    return <CheckBox key={p.id}
                     checked={checked}
                     label={p.operation}
                     onChange={e => this.togglePermission(p.id)} />;
  });
```

the checkbox looks like this:

```
const CheckBox = ({ checked, label, onChange }) => (
  <Input
          checked={checked}
          type="checkbox"
          label={prettyPrint(label)}
          onChange={onChange} />
);
```

and `this.togglePermssion` looks like this:

```
togglePermission(id) {
  this.props.togglePermissionOnRole(id);
}
```

What's happening is that when I toggle a checkbox, the redux action is dispatched and the component is re-rendered. When I toggle a checkbox again (the same or another), `this.togglePermission` is called again multiple times. As I toggle more checkboxes, the amount of times it's executed seems to grow exponentially.

Any ideas as to why this behaviour happens?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong here to me ?

Comment: Yeah more code would be helpful here. Can you show your implementation of `<Input />` and the rest of the render method where you use `list` ?

Comment: @azium it's `react-bootstrap` - I've added the rest of the render method but I think you'll find there's nothing else interesting there. 

@Omarjmh that was my bad - but both `onChange` and `onClick` produce the same behaviour. If what you're saying was the case, wouldn't a click start an infinite loop of method calls? That doesn't happen here.

Comment: @Omarjmh Agreed, it looks a bit weird, but actually it is just the `onChange` prop of the `CheckBox` component that is being passed to the `onChange` prop of the `input`. No infinite loop :-)

Comment: @Zen Where does the `togglePermissionOnRole` come from? What does it contain?

Comment: @Nicole it comes from react-redux's `@connect`, but the behaviour is the same if the `togglePermission` method contains a simple `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out - turns out it was Rollbar's JS snippet the whole time.